# How to remove folders with same name recursively?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, recursive

I have folder, that contains a lot of subfolders. Each subfolder contains folder with name `__pycache__`.

How to remove folders with name `__pycache__` in each subfolder from command line in Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521382/command-line-tool-to-delete-folder-with-a-specified-name-recursively-in-windows/521433#521433

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
for /d /r . %%d in (__pycache__) do @if exist "%%d" echo "%%d" && rd /s/q "%%d"
```